# Customize Ringtone Preference's Ringtone List

Tags: android, android-preferences, ringtone

Is it possible to customize/control the list of ringtones besides `ringtoneType`?

For example, to show only the subset of ringtones(in the red box) instead of the entire list.

[image]

---

Currently a `RigtonePreference` would shows list of ringtones available from my phone, which is filtered by `ringToneType`:

```
<RigtonePreference
    android:key="alarm"
    android:title="@string/alert"
    android:ringtoneType="alarm"
    android:persistent="false"
    android:showDefault="false"
    android:showSilent="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this.

It is a system provided and populated dialog, and there is no attribute which you can show to filter it to this extent, sorry.

Comment: Oh okay:) Too bad it can't be altered. Thanks for the answer :)